# Get the instance of related model and save

Tags: django

I need to create and save with the related model. My model looks like

```
 Class Abs(models.Model):
       detail = models.ForeignKey(Detail, ........)


 class Esc(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), ...)
       detail_parts = models.ForeignKey(Abs,....)
```

What I want to achieve is to create a new Abs and retrieve its instance and create a new Esc with user and detail_parts (related to model Abs)

inside view

```
    class AbsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
         def create(self, request, *args, ** kwargs):

            detail = request.data.get(detail) //
            res= super().create(request, *args, **kwargs) // how to get the instance ?
            a = Abs.objects.filter(detail=detail) // here it return integer(example 20)
            Esc.objects.create(user=user,detail_parts=a) // returns Detail.detail_parts must be a "Abs" instance
```

I tried

```
           Esc.objects.create(user=user,detail_parts=res)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Solve , this is my code

```
 det = Detail.objects.get(pk=detail)
 id = Abs.objects.create(detail=det, **kwargs)  
 Esc.objects.create(user=user, detail_parts=id)
```